# Converting Asp.Net web forms to Asp.Net MVC project makes build fail

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, migration

We are migrating a project from classic Asp.Net web forms to Asp.Net MVC.

I have followed the fours steps outlined here
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/webformmvcharmony.aspx
and all is working well.

Now I want to get Visual Studio to include MVC item templates in the "add new item" dialog.  So I add {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}; to the <projecttypeguids> element in the csproj file.

So this succeeds in adding MVC support to the Visual Studio "add new item" dialog, but now the build fails.  And it fails in the strangest way.  The three projects that make up the solution each complete with "build succeeded" but the process ends with a message
'========== Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped =========='

I am able to F5 debug, but I am not able to publish.

We are using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and migrating to MVC 2.0.

Anyone have any ideas why the build is failing after adding this project type guid?

Comment: Anything of interest in the Output window after you try to publish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to rearrange the order of the GUIDS in the `<projecttypeguids>` element.  When `{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}` is first on the list, the build succeeds.